# How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have the modrewrite rules skip the directory `vip`. I've tried a number of things as you can see below, but to no avail.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^vip$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^vip/.$ - [PT]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/vip 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How do I get modrewrite to entirely ignore the `/vip/` directory so that all requests pass directly to the folder?

#### Update:

As points of clarity:

- It's hosted on Dreamhost
- The folders are within a wordpress directory
- the /vip/ folder contains a webdav .htaccess etc (though I dont think this is important

Comment: On apache 2.2 you might need `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12575089/516748

Answer (score 137):

Try putting this before any other rules.

```
RewriteRule ^vip - [L,NC]
```

It will match any URI beginning `vip`.

- The `-` means do nothing.
- The `L` means this should be last rule; ignore everything following.
- The `NC` means no-case (so "VIP" is also matched).

Note that it matches anything *beginning* `vip`. The expression `^vip$` would match `vip` but not `vip/` or `vip/index.html`. The `$` may have been  your downfall. If you really want to do it right, you might want to go with `^vip(/|$)` so you don't match `vip-page.html`

Comment: BTW, I had the same problem a few weeks ago, and this worked for me on Apache/2.2.8 (UNIX).

Comment: why not use `RewriteRule ^vip/? - [L,NC]` to take care of the slash issue?

Comment: @Brandon That's essentially equivalent to `^vip`. It would match "vip" followed by a slash (maybe) and some other characters (maybe). We want to match "vip" exactly (`^vip$`) or any string that starts with "vip/" (`^vip/`).

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is the same as why the existing  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` don't work. The directory in question has a special .htaccess that is causing an error--the same will happen with a password protected directory.

Comment: This worked. I tweaked it for my own use though. To make it so that any "/vip/" folder works use "RewriteRule \/vip\/ - [L,NC]"

Comment: what will happen if I have redirection to https?

Answer (score 14):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This says if it's an existing file or a directory don't touch it. You should be able to access site.com/vip and no rewrite rule should take place.

Comment: He is right, these rules should be sufficient. The problem is that the directory is password protected. See the other answers below (including mine) which elaborate on this.

Answer (score 10):

The code you are adding, and all answers that are providing Rewrite rules/conditions are useless! The default WordPress code already does everything that you should need it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Those lines say "if it's NOT an existing file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`), pass it along to WordPress. Adding additional rules, not matter how specific or good they are, is redundant--you should already be covered by the WordPress rules!

So why aren't they working???

The `.htaccess` in the `vip` directory is throwing an error. The exact same thing happens if you password protect a directory.

Here is the solution:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /err.txt
ErrorDocument 403 /err.txt
```

Insert those lines before the WordPress code, and then create /err.txt. This way, when it comes upon your WebDAV (or password protected directory) and fails, it will go to that file, and get caught by the existing default WordPress condition (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`).

Comment: Regarding my upvote for this solution. I had an .htaccess password protecting the subdirectory which was passing through to index.php, the err.txt file, allowed my to mach the directory.

Comment: I had another folder under a wordpress directory that contained a separate php app.  That app was throwing an error, but instead of getting the error, it was coming back through wordpress and giving me a 404.  This solution solves that issue and I was able to see the 500 error that was being thrown by the php application.  Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a perfect solution for those who have issues with htpasswd-protected subfolders. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

In summary, the final solution is:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /misc/myerror.html
ErrorDocument 403 /misc/myerror.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I posted more about the cause of this problem in my specific situation, involving Wordpress and WebDAV on Dreamhost, which I expect many others to be having on [my site](http://codyaray.com/2010/08/wordpress-webdav-and-dreamhost).

Answer (score 8):

You mentioned you already have a .htaccess file in the directory you want to ignore - you can use

```
RewriteEngine off
```

In that .htaccess to stop use of mod_rewrite (not sure if you're using mod_rewrite in that folder, if you are then that won't help since you can't turn it off).

Comment: Wouldn't help, as the .htaccess in the parent directory, which does have Rewrite rules, would get evaluated long before Apache looked into /vip.

Comment: I just used this method and it worked fine. And I have .htaccess in the parent directory turning rewriteengine on. So I guess Apache looks in the child directory regardless.

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing this part of your code:

```
RewriteRule ^vip/.$ - [PT]
```

...with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(vip) [NC]
```

That should fix things up.

Comment: This helped me in a case where there was a general rule in place already (block all hidden directories that start with . ), but I needed to make one exception (allow .well-known for letsencrypt to work on cron).

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pilot/
```

is the way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the answer by **brentonstrine** (and I see **matdumsa** also had the same idea) was the right one... I wanted to up-vote their answers, but being new here, I have no "reputation", so I have to write a full answer, in order to emphasize what I think is the real key here.

Several of these answers would successfully stop the WordPress index.php from being used ... but in many cases, the reason for doing this is that there is a real directory with real pages in it that you want to display directly, and the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

lines already take care of that, so most of those solutions are a distraction in a case like mine.

The key was **brentonstrine's** insight that the error was a secondary effect, caused by the password-protection inside the directory I was trying to display directly. By putting in the

```
ErrorDocument 401 /err.txt
ErrorDocument 403 /err.txt
```

lines and creating error pages (I actually created err401.html and err403.html and made more informative error messages) I stopped the 404 response being generated when it couldn't find any page to display for 401 Authentication Required, and then the folder worked as expected... showing an apache login dialog, then the contents of the folder, or on failure, my error 401 page.

Comment: You could leave a comment instead of putting an answer too.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had the same issue using wordpress and found that the issue is linked with not having proper handler for 401 and 403 errors..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These conditions are already supposed not to rewrite the url of existing folders but they don’t do their job for password protected folders. In my case, adding the following two lines to my root .htaccess fixed the problem:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /misc/myerror.html
ErrorDocument 403 /misc/myerror.html
```

Of course you need to create the /misc/myerror.html,

Answer (score 3):

This works ...

```
RewriteRule ^vip - [L,NC]
```

But ensure it is the first rule after

RewriteEngine on

i.e.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^vip - [L,NC]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

etc
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your objective, but the following might do what you're after?

```
RewriteRule ^/vip/(.*)$   /$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This will cause a URL such as http://www.example.com/vip/fred.html to be rewritten without the /vip.