# How do I get modrewrite to not apply rules to a specific folder?

Tags: mod-rewrite

How do I get modrewrite to ENTIRELY ignore the /vip/ directory so that all requests pass directly to the folder?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^vip/.$ - [PT]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

See also [How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-modrewrite)  -- reposting because I wasn't sufficiently clear about the problem first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
RewriteRule ^vip/.$ - [PT]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^vip/.*$ - [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way I do it when needed is add a new .htaccess file to that folder and in it put

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

edited to fix typo