# .htaccess !-f rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been using simple mod_rewrite rules for my CMS for years and am now making a new version, I am seeing the rewriteCond not making sense- I have the standard "if is not a file" but I still see the rewriterules being evaluated even though they're not supposed to. My rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2
```

I load /page/var and it works fine as index.php?page=page&var=var, but I try to load /css/file.css and it loads index.php?page=css&var=file.css even though /css/file.css ***is*** a file, so the whole rewrite section shouldn't even be evaluated.

I've never seen htaccess apparently defy its own logic, can someone help me figure this out? Has anyone ever run across anything like this?

Answer (score 28):

The `RewriteCondition`s only apply to the next rule.   You want this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2
```

Comment: That's great, after all these years doing mod_rewrites like this it turns out my logic worked by accident... thanks so much

Comment: awesome, thank you!!.. it's also good to keep in mind that if the file  doesn't exists, it will NOT 404, it will just pass it to the next rule.

Comment: @Colin - my sentiments exactly. Now I have to figure out whether that's a relief, or a worry...

Comment: @Greg - By using this condition **RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2** , The URL remains **same**.Please help me on this

Comment: @Roberto, Based on this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
**RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2**, The URL remains same. I need to change the URL

Comment: I literally spent 2 hours figuring this out on my own! Rather annoying that all the other searches I came up with didn't yield this. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Apache 2.2, then you MUST read this:

http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/

Spoiler: what you will need to write is actually:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Merc.

Comment: I've been looking for this for sooo long, totally solved my problem (I'm not using vhost, but container). Thanks!

Comment: Since the asker won't accept an answer, it would be great if my answer got the most upvotes really...

Comment: I found out this by myself, but I had to search StackOverflow for an answer like this one, just to give an upvote somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that should work.

Try setting the following props in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteLog /var/log/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

To debug your requests. Remember to reset this value once you're done, otherwise you'll end up with a filled up harddrive.

Comment: +1 for the RewriteLog stuff, it helped me debug my rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to debug what it's doing?

(From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)