# Apache RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a few problems with our company website. My colleague left the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
# Files in this directory will override the
# controlled equivalent.

# First, set up URL rewriting
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Forbid access to .htaccess files
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^php\.ini$ - [F]

# This Apache mod_rewrite rule checks to see
# if the requested file exists as either a file
# or a directory, if it doesn't then we rewrite 
# to the respective controlled location (unless
# we're already there!).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*/_control/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _control/$1 [L]
```

Everything was working OK but about a week ago, our mysite.com/admin and 404 page started redirecting to the hosting company's website. I investigated further and seems like the problem lies in the last four lines. As per Greg's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/697980/1933380 I changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*/_control/.*$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _control/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work either. The folder structure looks like:

[image]

Am I missing something or making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RewriteCond lines are combined with a logical AND, so it only makes sense to write them twice if you have 2 RewriteRule lines.

I think it must be like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_control/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_control/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I got the virtual directory working. There's another set of .htaccess rules for 404 pages. I have posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014590/apache-404-url-not-working . Thought you might be interested.