# How can I convince mod_rewrite to stay away from my Subversion repositories?

Tags: svn, apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site [hosted on DreamHost], using WordPress for the main content, but Subversion repositories in http://mysite/svn .

My file layout is:

```
webroot/
  blog   # wordrpress files
  .htaccess
```

My SVN repositories lay outside the web root, but they are correctly mapped to /svn/repository URLs.

When I put the WordPress permalink rewrite rules in my .htaccess file, the blog pages and permalinks work great, but it breaks Subversion.

This is my .htaccess file with everything extraneous removed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# try 1                                                                                       
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} svn [NC]                                                          
#RewriteRule . - [PT,L]                                                                       

# try 2                                                                                       
#RewriteRule ^svn.*  -  [PT,L]                                                                

# try 3
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^svn 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . blog/index.php [L]
```

The very last line breaks Subversion.  Clients errors are like this:

```
$ svn ls https://mysite/svn/myrepo/
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn': 405 Method Not Allowed (https://mysite)
```

If I comment out that last line, `RewriteRule . blog/index.php`, Subversion works.  But having WordPress handle the the nice permalink stuff doesn't.

I tried the three "ignore any URL starting with 'svn'" approaches I've commented out above, and none work-- they seem to not do ANYTHING.  With or without the PT pass-through flag.

I have googled quite a bit and it seems others have been stumped with mod_rewrite and WebDAV (which Subversion uses) stepping on each other.  I found [an extremely similar abandoned SO question here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/), but no working solutions.  Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should call Dreamhost's support. I have some websites with them and always had good support.

Anyways, what about [this solution](http://www.minuk.net/2009/10/24/subversion-wordpress-htaccess-fun/)?

SVN repository (SVNRepo)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} SVNRepo
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I chatted with a support person who said mod rewrite issues are outside their scope.  :(

Comment: and it is, apparently, `%{THE_REQUEST}` that makes the crucial difference between try #1 and the working solution.  Not any of the flags like `[L]` or  `[NC]`

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked for you! As the official mod_rewrite documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html says, "Despite the tons of examples and docs, mod_rewrite is voodoo. Damned cool voodoo, but still voodoo.".

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/svn.*
```

?

Comment: In particular, `%{REQUEST_URI}` isn't subject to local directory stripping (which removes the leading '/'), whereas the current URL is stripped for RewriteRules, hence the need for the slash in the RewriteCond.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's the solution, I forgot about the need of / in my answer.

Comment: This variant of try #3 also makes the svn client return `405 Method Not Allowed`.  Does not work.

Comment: Can you try it on variant #1 and #2, adding the leading slash?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered moving your Subversion repositories to a different subdomain? For example, http://svn.mysite.com/

This would be an easy way out.

I've spent many hours pulling my hair out over mod_rewrite...any time you can avoid that, it's a win.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm trying to avoid that because I want secure (HTTPS) subversion and I only want to buy and manage one SSL cert and static IP.   I feel I *should* be able to do this with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Try #3 looks good, have you tried there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^svn.*
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work either.

I don't understand, because any of those 3 things *should* be keeping the blog/index.php RewriteRule from firing, right?  And if I comment out the index.php RewriteRule, it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)svn(.*)
```

Comment: That's going to catch everything that has "svn" somewhere. Too broad.

Comment: This variant of try #3 does not work.  Still yields `405 Method Not Allowed` with the svn client.