# Controlling children paths with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have a site that is running a CMS under a subfolder, but rather than having it load up like http://mysite.tld/cms/, I want all of the pages to load as though they're located at the root of http://mysite.tld.

So far I've been able to accomplish a portion of this such that index files are loading up at http://mysite.tld/, however when I start to reach out into child pages I end up getting http://mysite.tld/cms/some-page instead of http://mysite.tld/some-page.

My .htaccess so far is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.tld$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cms [L]
```

I can't help but think there must be something that I'm missing on .htaccess that would facilitate subpages to work as well within the root rather than at the `/cms/` path?

Comment: Something like this should work: `RewriteRule ^cms/(.*) /$1   [L]`

Comment: @faa actually I think you're about spot on here.  I have been able to get pages now, however assets are not being found such as the stylesheets and other dependent resources.  Even though, I'm having to include within the root an index.php file that initiates a require to the subdirectory so I feel I'm not getting things set quite right in .htaccess yet.

Comment: Technically it seems as though I could have only `ReeriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cms/$1` to do the trick, but yet I get these missing resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163530/320681) works:

> RewriteRule ^foldername – [L,NC]

- The – means do nothing.
- The L means this should be last rule; ignore everything following.
- The NC means no-case (so “FOLDERNAME” is also matched).

***The Rails method also works:***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(folders|to|ignore).*
RewriteRule .* – [L]
```