# Hide some directories from Wordpress without breaking Wordpress 404 messages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block Wordpress from messing with `/example` and `/example2`, as I had some advanced things (e.g. password protection) that Wordpress was breaking and incorrectly giving 404 messages to.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php parking-page.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(example|example/.*|example2|example2/.*).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This works to block Wordpress from those folders, but now Wordpress won't catch bad URLs anymore unless they have a `/` in them.
For example, Wordpress will catch:

```
mydomain.com/something/
mydomain.com/something/anything
mydomain.com/something/anything.html
```

but it won't catch

```
mydomain.com/something
mydomain.com/something.html
```

(even if `mydomain.com/something` is a valid WP page that would normally work if I didn't have the %{REQUEST_URI} line in there)

The latter type of URL is given the server 404 messages. How can I keep Wordpress in the loop on everything but those two directories?

Comment: Why the slash in the WP regex. Here: `./`? It should be `.` With the slash it seems is matching only second level directories in the URL structure.

Comment: do you mean 
`RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]` should be `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` ?

Comment: I made that change, but it doesn't seem to have changed the behavior. `mycomain.com/pagename/` works but `mydomain.com/pagename` breaks.

Comment: Well, that's the way it should be. About your question, at least for me it is not clear. What have the folders `exampleN` have to do with `folders `something`, for example? What do you mean with `How can I keep Wordpress in the loop...`? In short, what do you want to achieve with mod_rewrite directives, if anything?

Comment: Here is an example. I have a wordpress page named "privacy". Normally, you can get to that page by typing `domain.com/privacy` or `domain.com/privacy/`. However, right now, only the latter works, e.g. it *must* have a `/` for Wordpress to get at it and build the page. Same principle applies for 404 pages.

Comment: The rule-set in your question is the WP standard one that works fine, except for the line `(example...`. From your update I guess everything works as expected when that line is removed. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, everything works as expected when the line is removed... except that I have some special things happening in `/example` and `/example2`, so if I remove that line, everything in those directories breaks. Wordpress gives me 404 no matter what in those directories even though there is nothing wrong with them. That is why I need to exclude Wordpress from intercepting anything in those directories.

Comment: Yes, I understand the reason for the condition but it seems the regex is the problem. You may try this instead: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(example|example2) [NC]`

Comment: Hm, I tried it but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I did not answer the question because I am not sure what's exactly the problem. But we know where it is, so try modifying that regex and/or moving the condition to another position (Above the previous rule, for example). You almost got it anyway. Don't forget to clear the browser's cache before any test.

Comment: Documentation on rewrite rules has totally confounded me. I still can't figure out how they even work. Can you suggest a good resource to learn how to use RewriteRule and RewriteCond?

Comment: For me, Apache docs are always the best source. Look for them in Apache site. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the solution ([hat-tip](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-getting-wordpress-and-password-protected-files-to-play-well-together#post-750550)). It is the exact same issue as on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157129/925897), except whereas his problem was that the directory in question was using WebDAV, my problem was that the directory was using password protection.

In essence, the default WordPress rules should work as they are--but they break when the folder is password protected. These rules that should catch it as a file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`) fail:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It wasn't catching my password protected directory as a file or directory because it was stuck at the password prompt--and I didn't have any error pages to send it to. Thus, the solution is to set up error handling:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /err.txt
ErrorDocument 403 /err.txt
```

Just put these two lines above all the WordPress stuff and create `/err.txt`. That way it can land on the file and the default WP code works beautifully.