# mod_rewrite To Redirect everything within a directory except for the directory itself

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm going to be using Wordpress as a new CMS for my site, and will be using the permalinks for many of the pages. The problem is there are many old pages and files outside of Wordpress that need to remain within directories that overlap with the permalinks. For example, a permalink for a WP page would be at:
http://www.domain.com/support/

But I have several php apps and other files that people still use within the /support/ directory that need to be accessed by the same URLs. If there is a directory in the same place as the permalink then the permalink is ignored.

I've been researching this and found that I can probably rename the physical directory (to "A-support", for example), and then redirect everything except for a url pointing to the exact directory to the new location.

So this should not redirect:
http://www.domain.com/support/

But all of these should redirect to the new /A-support/ directory location:
http://www.domain.com/support/page.html
http://www.domain.com/support/subdirectory/
http://www.domain.com/support/subdirectory/page.html

Here is the .htaccess rule I have so far that doesn't seem to be working, as it will simply redirect everything to directly within the /A-support/ folder, and not work for subdirectories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} support/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !support/(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^support/(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/A-support/ [L]
```

I've looked at the docs but it's a relatively confusing function for me and I can't seem to get it right.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite

Comment: Hi Peter. Those are a different question. I'm not trying to simply ignore a directory from my rewrites, I want everything within the directory to redirect properly, just not the specifi url that goes exactly to the directory's location.

Comment: The comments and answers in those questions answer the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope. They are trying to have directories ignored during rewrite rules, I'm trying to have a directory's contents forwarded to another directory. This was already answered with a completely different solution from the linked posts because it isn't the same question.

Comment: Apologies, I got that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^support/(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/A-support/$1 [L]
```

The main thing that you're missing is the `$1` backreference. This shouldn't redirect `/support/` and only anything within it. You don't need any of the other conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like this is working perfectly. Sometimes I just love StackOverflow.