# magento under wordpress as subdirectory not working

Tags: wordpress, magento

I am using godaddy server.

I have wordpress as root directory and i have setup magento from local to server inside root as subdirectory.

Magento home page is working fine,but when i try to open any supage of magento then it opens "About us" page without CSS of root wordpress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the RewriteBase statement in Magento .htaccess ?

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

become

```
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
```

Comment: Yes, i have checked it, but not working. My subdomain link is,
(http://shreeyaitsolutions.com/sub-domains/magentostore/)

Comment: Ok maybe you should add a rule inside the Wordpress htaccess for ignore the Magento directory... Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite

Comment: Found this that can help http://www.measureddesigns.com/magento-wordpress-integration-htaccess-index-files/

Comment: I see you have finded how to do. Why don't share the solution with others ?

Comment: Yes, I found solution. 
RewriteBase /sub-domains/magentostore/

Comment: Well so please upvote/accept my answer since it's what i suggested ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured correctly you don't need to set `RewriteBase`, but make sure your base url is set correctly in backend as `{server-root}/subdirectory/`. If you cannot access admin, you'll need to change data in `core_config_data` by searching fields by url and setting the correct value by for example `phpMyAdmin`. Otherwise you'll need to do it by ssh + mysql command... or reinstall your Magento instance giving correct url to the installer.

Comment: Yes, i have checked this also. It also display correct one.