# htAccess exclude directory

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I already searched for the answer in other questions and tried a few solutions with no luck:

In the root of my website I use the following code in .htaccess and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But now I need to define that when I'm in the /admin directory it has to act normal.
Because when for example I link a stylesheet in a file in /admin, I have to define the src as "/admin/something.css" because else it will look for domain.com/css/something.css

Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added:

```
RewriteRule ^admin - [L,NC]
```

Before anything else.

- The **-** means do nothing.
- The **L** means this should be last rule; ignore everything following.
- The **NC** means no-case (so "ADMIN" is also matched).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite)