# 404 Error - codeigniter and htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I uploaded my project to a sub domain of my website. On that sub domain I installed wordpress on it and installed codeingiter to directory called app. The default controller is set to login which shows up when I go to the app/ url but once I click on any of the links "app/create-account or app/login" it takes me to wordpress default 404 error page. I am using codeingiter 3 and have been trying for a few days to get this working correctly. My class names are according to the styles required (ucfirst) and I believe it is something to with my htaccess file. Everything works fine on my localhost.

Current htaccess file in my codeingiter directory "/app/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Current wordpress htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/app(/*)? - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^/app - [L,NC]` just after `RewriteBase /`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite).

Comment: Edited my wordpress htaccess to add that line you sent me. Its weird because if I login to wordpress and then go to my /app/ directory where it ask me to login if its the default route it shows the page. If I go to app/login  which is what the default route is set to, I get wordpress 404 page error instead of codeigniters. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Or maybe `RewriteRule ^/app(/*)? - [L,NC]`.

Comment: Updated my htaccess to the above section. I did notice that when it takes me to wordpress 404 error page when I am supposed to be on the codeingiter  "/app/" section it has my active menu link set to blog. Not sure if that helps in any way. Thanks for your suggestions!