# Add exception to mod_rewrite rule to not fire for specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule on my site so that e.g.

```
example.com/category.php?cat=this becomes example.com/this/
```

And

```
example.com/category.php?cat=this&post=example becomes example.com/this/example/
```

This is the mod_rewrite as defined in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

    # Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$              category.php?cat=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$      post.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^blog-([^/]*).php$      default.php?page=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I need to set up OSCart on the site, and I'm going to put it in a folder called **printshop** so I would access it via:

```
example.com/printshop/
```

How would I modify my mod_rewrite so that it doesn't think I am calling this page:

```
example.com/category.php?cat=printshop
```

e.g. change the mod_rewrite to not fire for specific directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - a simple google search got me the answer:

```
RewriteRule ^printshop - [L,NC]
```

Found here:
[How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite)