# How can I allow access to my .well-known/ directory with CakePHP?

Tags: php, ssl, cakephp, encryption, lets-encrypt

I have the CakePHP framework installed on my `www.vimundos.com` linux server, before installing CakePHP in my `public_html`, I issued a SSL certificate successfully using Let's Encrypt which created a `.well-known/acme-challenge/` directory containing some content crucial to the certificate.

Of course after installing the framework, my certificate was removed. CakePHP is not allowing direct access to the directory, I tried using the `Route::redirect()` feature to map `.well-known/*` urls to the directory, but i only get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to do with CakePHP here. You need to update your .htaccess file (if using Apache) or nginx config not overwrite ./well-known/acme-challenge URL. Something like here: [How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

It's implicit from what's in the question that you have this:

```
public_html
    composer.json
    .htaccess
    index.php
    ...
    webroot
        .htaccess
        index.php
        css
        img
        js
    .well-known
```

Whatever version of CakePHP you are using, *nothing* outside the webroot directory is supposed to be directly accessible, and as such neither is the `.well-known` folder.

There's a very simple solution, just move it into the webroot directory:

```
public_html
    composer.json
    .htaccess
    index.php
    ...
    webroot
        .htaccess
        .well-known <- moved
        index.php
        css
        img
        js
```

Note that "webroot" is supposed to be the apache document root if at all possible (a production style install), not a folder *in* the document root (a development style install).